# The limit of an integral involving Fourier expansion

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, analysis

$F_n(t)=\frac{1}{2n\pi}$ $(\frac{\sin \frac{nt}{2}}{\sin \frac{t}{2}})^2$

Proof

$\int_{\delta\le |t|\le \pi} F_n(t) dt\rightarrow 0 ,n\rightarrow +\infty$

My attempt

$\frac{1}{2}+\cos t+\cos 2t+\dots +\cos nt=\frac{\sin \frac{(2n+1)t}{2}}{2\sin\frac{t}{2}}$——(1)

And 
$$\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\sin (m+\frac{1}{2})t=\frac{\sin ^2\frac{nt}{2}}{\sin \frac{t}{2}}$$

So $\int_{\delta\le |t|\le \pi} F_n(t) dt= \frac{1}{2n\pi} \int_{\delta\le |t|\le \pi} \frac{\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\sin (m+\frac{1}{2})t}{\sin\frac{t}{2}}dt$
And use the (1)the integral can be change to some integral of cos blabla but i don’t know what should I do next

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the raw form of $F_n(t)$. It's quite a simple estimate. We have
$$
\frac{1}{2n\pi}\frac{ \sin^2 \frac{nt}{2}}{\sin^2 \frac{t}{2}}\le \frac{1}{2n\pi}\frac{1}{\sin^2 \frac{\delta}{2}},
$$ for $\delta\le|t|\le \pi$ and
$$
\int_{\delta\le |t|\le \pi} F_n(t) dt\le \int_{\delta\le |t|\le \pi} \frac{1}{2n\pi}\frac{1}{\sin^2 \frac{\delta}{2}} dt\le \frac{1}{n}\frac{1}{\sin^2 \frac{\delta}{2}}\to 0
$$ as $n\to \infty$.